# Search shows question as not having an accepted answer, but an answer was accepted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Search for *emacs* (the word, not a tag). On the second page of search hits, you will see an entry for [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2284/keys-in-mode-maps/3635#3635) which has an accepted answer (from some time ago), but the search-hit entry does not indicate acceptance.

[image]

Seems like a bug.

Comment: +1 for red hand-made circle :)

Answer (score 3):

That search result is pointing to the *Answer*, not a *question*. The Question does not contain the word 'emacs', though the answer does. Answers do not get the accepted decoration....

Comment: Thanks. But you are explaining away the problem as *status quo*: that's just how it works. How about an enhancement that shows, for answer search hits also, *whether the question has an accepted answer*? And maybe even shows whether the particular answer search hit listed **is** the accepted answer.

Comment: @Drew - fair point, I will remove the by-design designator, and draw some dev-eyes on to it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, perhaps status-by-design applies, as that is the current design. I guess my question amounts to an enhancement request to improve the design slightly.

Comment: @Drew you should consider asking a rephrased question tagged either [meta-tag:discussion] or [meta-tag:feature-request] on parent meta.